# WebClient.DownloadString returning no data

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm experiencing a strange issue with `WebClient.DownloadString` that I can't seem to solve, my code:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim html = client.DownloadString("http://www.btctrade.com/")
```

The content doesn't seem to be fully AJAX, so it can't be that. Is it due to the web page being in Chinese? I'm guessing HTML is just served as HTML, so can't really be that either. The URL is fine when I go to it and there seems to be no redirects to https either.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set cookies and useragent in the webclient headers this works

```
client .Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "UserAgent,Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1");
client .Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "USER_PW=9b1283bfe37ac47b243a1e0c9c1c9e52; PHPSESSID=f692406a0c84dba2605a7065d55a3b53")
```

and if u want that the request do all this work , you have to user httpwebrequest then save all the response's headers and use them in a new request

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out now, much appreciated for the detailed response.

Comment: Absolutely saved me here - this works a treat. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` is not buggy, so probably the server is returning data you did not expect. Use Fiddler to watch what happens when you go to the site in a web browser.

When I executed your code the web site returned no data. When I visited the site in a web browser it returned data. **Probably, the site is detecting that you are a bot and denying you access.** Fake being a browser by mimicking what you see in Fiddler.

Comment: I've done this and seen that the content seems to be decoded before inspection (Fiddler) - even this alone seems like a nightmare, but you've put me on the right path here so I'll accept your reply :)

Comment: The site is sending gzipped content. Fiddler can decode it so that you can inspect it. WebClient can also auto-decompress.

Comment: Sorry for removing this as the correct answer, but the other solution worked perfectly.

Comment: That's your choice. On the other hand, this answer tells you *why* and it will also help future visitors more to solve their issue (for different websites). Just being told "add this magic header" would not have helped you understand. In the future, you'd have been helpless to similar issues. Questions are not just for one person, but for all dozens of future visitors as well.